# inserting python variable into mysql table doesn't work

Tags: python, mysql

i've a problem with using mysql with python i want to store variable into a table at mysql , it shows me that the code insert only row 1 while running table no values are recoded even in row1 no records at all , i want to store 10 values then remove them all in a loop but i want delay between each value and the next 5 seconds ,that's the code and what appear , and sorry for my english :) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vdcl8.png)

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python
import time
import datetime
import MySQLdb
db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost", db="project")
curs = db.cursor()
i = 0
while True :
     while i < 10 :
        i = i+1
        w=("""INSERT INTO zzz(tem,dat) VALUES (%s, %s)""" ,(i, datetime.datetime.now()))
        curs.execute(*w)
        time.sleep(5)
        print i
     b = "DELETE FROM `zzz`"
     curs.execute(b)
     db.commit()
```

Comment: Why are you definining the throw-away variable `w` instead of just supplying that as arguments directly? Also `"""` is for multi-line strings and just clutters this query up for no reason.

Comment: i've tried just " and i've tried executing inserting this 
curs.execute("INSERT INTO zzz(tem,dat) VALUES (%s, %s)" ,(i, datetime.datetime.now()))
not working

Comment: If you only commit the transaction after the `DELETE` operation, then whatever other session you're trying to inspect the database mid-transaction will not see the uncommitted state due to *transaction isolation*...

Comment: but the problem occur before delete commit the main problem that while i<10 doesn't work it prints iterations but can't store them that what appear while running python code

version2.py:12: Warning: (1292L, "Incorrect date value: '2018-01-19 13:16:58.427604' for column 'dat' at row 1")
  curs.execute(*w)
1
version2.py:12: Warning: (1292L, "Incorrect date value: '2018-01-19 13:17:03.434248' for column 'dat' at row 1")
  curs.execute(*w)
2
version2.py:12: Warning: (1292L, "Incorrect date value: '2018-01-19 13:17:08.440239' for column 'dat' at row 1")
  curs.execute(*w)
3

Comment: MySQL may not support microseconds. Try passing up through seconds: `datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")`. And be sure to `db.commit()` after the append query.

Comment: oh that works thank you it starts to record but now how to delete 10 values then start to record them again